# Set<Pointer> comparison struct

Tags: c++, pointers, set, operator-overloading

I have the following comparison struct for a set of pointers. Could anyone explain why the < is illegal?

```
struct RowPtrComp
{
    bool operator()(const Row*& first, const Row*& second)
    {
        return *first < *second;
    }
};
```

I have visited several similar questions, but none of them quite answered my question.

Comment: Have you provided a < overload for your Row type?

Comment: Note that its not necesary, but is a good practice to make the () overload of a comparator const

Comment: I have implemented the operator< in Row, yes.

Comment: Could you provide the declaration/implementation of that overload?

Comment: Please post your all relevant code, and compile error message, or runtime error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the operator function as `const`

```
struct RowPtrComp
{
    bool operator()(const Row*& first, const Row*& second) const  //  <--
    {
        return *first < *second;
    }
};
```